# C++ Segmentation Fault Passing Class Variables to Class Functions

Tags: c++11, vector, segmentation-fault

So I'm trying to have a class variable that is a vector and pass it in between some class functions.  A basic version of what I'm trying to do is captured in the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class isingModel {
    private:
        int length;

    public:
        void set_values (int);
        void ising_Iterator(vector<vector<int> > & );
        vector<vector<int> >  lattice;
};


void isingModel::set_values (int l) {
    length = l;
    vector<vector<int> > lattice(length, vector<int>(length));

    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<length;j++){
                int randNum = rand() % 2; // Generate a random number either 0 or 1
                lattice[i][j]=2*(randNum-.5); //shift value so that it is either 1 or -1.
        }
    }
}

void isingModel::ising_Iterator (vector<vector<int> > & lattice) {

    lattice[0][0]=1;

}



int main () {
    int L;
    cout << "Enter the length of the lattice: ";
    cin >> L;

    isingModel iModel;

    iModel.set_values(L);
    iModel.ising_Iterator(iModel.lattice );
    return 0;
}
```

So I have a class that has some functions, but my main goal is to make a class variable vector and then pass it to different class functions.  In this code I make vector called lattice and set it's values in set_values and then after passing lattice to ising_Iterator by reference and want to change some values in lattice.   According to the documentation and other questions I thought I would have to pass the vector by reference (hence the & in the function declaration).  But I seem to still getting segmentation fault.  I used gdb to discover that the problem is in ising_Iterator, so it must be that the class function ising_Iterator does not have access to the lattice vector.  One of the reasons I'm so confused is that if I replace

```
void isingModel::ising_Iterator (vector<vector<int> > & lattice) {

    lattice[0][0]=1;

}
```

with

```
void isingModel::ising_Iterator (vector<vector<int> > & lattice) {

    length=1;

}
```

everything compiles and runs fine.  So I've concluded that passing class variables that are vectors to class functions and changing them is fundamentally different then just passing class variables to class function and changing them there..

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<vector<int> > lattice(length, vector<int>(length));
```

What did you think this was doing? What it actually does is to declare a function-local `vector` with the same name as the member variable. This *shadows/hides* the member and means you're actually altering a locally scoped variable, not the persistent member - because the duplicate name that 'wins' is the one in the nearest scope.

So, you're changing a local variable named `lattice` in the method `set_values()`. Such changes, by definition, cannot reach anything outwith this function. The local variable then goes out of scope, without having been copied or otherwise 'sent' anywhere, and so all of your changes to it are inconsequential.

Your later attempt to access the *member* variable named `lattice` within the method `ising_Iterator()`, assuming that you had altered *it* to have non-zero size, fail because you didn't. On indexing, boom: segfault.

Anyway, why do you think you have to pass any member variable around among instance functions? All methods have full access to class members. That's... kind of the whole point of using a class. Passing a member variable between member functions - while your closing speculation is false and it would work fine if done properly - is pointless at best, a waste of resources at worst.

Remove the shadowing local, stop passing around references to the member, and just use member variables directly within your methods. It'll work.